# Can XSD 1.0 require attributes based upon the type of an element?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-1.0

I have this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vehicle_list>
    <vehicle id="v001">
        <type registration="ABC-XYZ" year="2010">car</type>
        <spent_fuel>8</spent_fuel>
        <constructor>XPTO</constructor>
    </vehicle>  
    <vehicle id="v002">
        <type>bike</type>
        <spent_fuel>0</spent_fuel>
        <constructor>XIMA</constructor>
    </vehicle>
    <vehicle id="v003">
        <type>boat</type>
        <spent_fuel>40</spent_fuel>
        <constructor>AnyBoat</constructor>
    </vehicle>
</vehicle_list>
```

Now I need (for study purpose) to make an XSD, in which I use enumeration to make restriction on the type of vehicles (car, bike and boat) and defining the rule, that if the type is "car" then I need to have two attributes: registration and year.

How should I manage to do that?

I've been reading but can't find anything yet that help me to find the solution.

I am limited to XSD 1.0 (not XSD 1.1).

Comment: The question is that I can't use XSD 1.1, only XSD 1.0. It seems that it is not possible to do. As far as I could read in those questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSD 1.0 cannot express a constraint based on the value of an element.  You need XSD 1.1 assertions for that, and you stated in a comment that you can only use XSD 1.0.

Really, however, if you fix your XML design, you don't need XSD 1.1.  Rather than having a generic `vehicle` that requires further specification via a `type` element, just promote the `type` element value to be an proper element itself.

To wit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vehicle_list>
    <car id="v001" registration="ABC-XYZ" year="2010">
        <spent_fuel>8</spent_fuel>
        <constructor>XPTO</constructor>
    </car>  
    <bike id="v002">
        <spent_fuel>0</spent_fuel>
        <constructor>XIMA</constructor>
    </bike>
    <boat id="v003">
        <spent_fuel>40</spent_fuel>
        <constructor>AnyBoat</constructor>
    </boat>
</vehicle_list>
```

It is then trivial to write an XSD 1.0 for this XML design.

Comment: Thank you, with that fix on the XML and using

    <xsd:choice>
                <xsd:element name="car" type="car_type"/>
                <xsd:element name="bike" type="bike_type"/>
                <xsd:element name="boat" type="boat_type"/>
     </xsd:choice>
i managed to write the XSD file.
Once again, thanks for the help.

Comment: @kjhughes can you show the solution for this in XSD 1.1 using assertions

Comment: @Ysh: Please create a new question.   State that you're able to use XSD 1.1 (check, because not all XSD processors support XSD 1.1) and include your XML and initial XSD attempt.  Thanks.